# How to use OFSET and FETCH for table with JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a pretty simple case with two tables:

```
create table Table1
(
    Id int,
    Name varchar(255),
)
```

and

```
create table Table2
(
    Id int,
    Name varchar(255),
    ParentId int
)
```

I want to get some count of rows (for example offset 10 and fetch 5) by Table1 with joining of Table2. Between Table1 and Table2 I have a relation one-to-many.

I try to write something like that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON Table1.Id = t2.ParentId 
ORDER BY Table1.Id 
    OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
```

As a result I get 5 rows from joined tables. But I want to get 5 rows from Table1 and then join to them Table2. Have someone any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Tag only with the database you are using.  MySQL or Postgres?

Comment: You need a subquery or CTE too produce the paged results and join it to Table2

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM Table1
      ORDER BY Id
      OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY) AS t1
JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.Id = t2.ParentId
```

Thank you all! That was easy)